# Unable to run WIF for WCF MSDN sample

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to use the sample code provided here to create a secure WCF service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161104(v=vs.110).aspx

I followed the steps as mentioned, however, I am getting the following exceptions in the client code:

> No version of the CardSpace service was found to be installed on the
>   machine. Please install CardSpace and retry the operation.

and sometimes

> The channel is configured to use interactive initializer
>   'System.ServiceModel.Security.InfocardInteractiveChannelInitializer',
>   but the channel was Opened without calling DisplayInitializationUI. 
>   Call DisplayInitializationUI before calling Open or other methods on
>   this channel.

Calling `DisplayInitializationUI()` explicitly gives the `CardSpace` exception as well

Is there some configuration I am missing?